# How to send PHP email after posting data to Database

Tags: php, jquery, email, phpmailer

I am currently working on a quote form. After submitting the form, there was an email set to send submitted record back to client as copy. However, as I was using Mandrill for transaction emails, it's no longer free. I don't want to use any paid service and am now looking to send the same email using PHPMailer. I am finding it difficult to understand to call php to send email. Any help? I am open for options. All I want to send email after form submits.

email.js

```
     function finalize_things(data, order_id){

        //posting data to the server side page
        $.post(window.location.origin+'/post/', data,function(response){
                if(response == 'success'){
                console.log(response);
                send_email(order_id, data.email, data.firstname, data.project_details, data.file_names);

           } else {

                console.log(response);
                alert('order not placed.');}
         });
       }


    function send_email(order_id, email, firstname, project_details, file_names){

           var html_message = "message here"

        data = {

                "key": "xxxxxxxxx",
                "message": {

                    "html": html_message,
                    "text": "",
                    "subject": "Your subject",
                    "from_email": "test@test.com",
                    "from_name": "Company name",

                    "to": [{
                        "email": email,
                        "name": firstname
                        }
                     ]},

                "async": false
            };

        $.ajax({url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',

                type: 'POST',

                data: data,

                success: function(resp){

                    console.log(resp); }
              });
```

PHPMAILER Code:

```
        include_once '/../../PHPMailer/cms_db.php';
        require_once '/../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        require_once '/../../PHPMailer/config.php';

        if (isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) {


        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication

        $mail->Host = $smtp_server;                 // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->Username = $username;                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = $password;                // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom("companyemail@xyz.com", "Company Name");

        $mail->addAddress($email, $firstname);   // Add a recipient

        $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

        $bodyContent = "test message";

        $mail->Subject = "Your Quote ID";
        $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;
        $mail->AltBody = $bodyContent;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Message could not be sent.";
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo.'</strong></div>';
        } else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Message has been sent</strong></div>';
        }
        }
```

Comment: What part are you not understanding?  Could you be more specific?

Comment: How can I use php email code in JavaScript? Like after console.log, it sends an email and How can i send email after posting the data with phpmailer. What to do with $.AJAX.. should I use it or remove it...?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you don't want to use external services like gmail... You need to set up your own mail server (postfix, sendmail etc.) Please note, that webservers very often has potfix onboard (httpd + php + mysql + postfix) already.
Has your hosting postfix already? Check this by using [standard mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), php script like :

```
<?php
$to = 'yourmail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'test subj';
$mail_body = 'test body';
mail($to, $subject, $mail_body);
?>
```

If it works -- write your own script based on this code or use phpmailer (it has settings for local mail daemon)

PS PHPMailer can send mail via extenal webserver, like gmail https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps (key line here: `$mail->isSMTP();`) or via *local* server, such as postfix -- see [example here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/sendmail.phps) -- key line is `$mail->isSendmail();`
and your current code snippet is for using EXTERNAL service, not for LOCAL!

Comment: Thanks AK. I have web hosting with bluehost so I can send emails with SMTP. The only issue I have how... I just want this php mailer code run to send an email when any clients submits the form, how to add this code in my email.js code... Can you change the email.js code with gmail api to make it worked.... In mandril, JSON api was used.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your js this line:

`$.ajax({url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',`

to:

`$.ajax({url: 'http://yourserver.tld/send_phpmailer.php',`

And use something like this in send_phpmailer.php:

```
<?php

//////  Part 1. Set up variables

$key = $_POST['key']; // need for mandrill, you can omit this
$html = $_POST['message']['html'];
$text = $_POST['message']['text'];
$subject = $_POST['message']['subject'];
$from_email = $_POST['message']['from_email'];
$from_name = $_POST['message']['from_name'];
$to_email = $_POST['message']['to']['email'];
$to_name = $_POST['message']['to']['name'];

//////  Part 2. Including PHPMailer
include_once '/../../PHPMailer/cms_db.php';
require_once '/../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once '/../../PHPMailer/config.php';

//////  Part 3. Sending letter by PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom( $from_email, $from_name);

//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($to_email, $to_name);

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $subject;

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML($html);

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = $text;

//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks AK, let me give it a try. Can I use direct page name instead of complete path? Like $.ajax({url: 'send_phpmailer.php', because both email.js, and send_phpmailer would be in same folder.

Comment: Sure, you can use file name only in case if js and php are in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

i try this coding in my own way

```html
<?php
include ('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
        $phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['phone']);
        $msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['msg']);
        
        
        $sql="insert into contact(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`msg`) values('$name','$email','$phone','$msg')";
    //  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        
        
         if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){ 
                $to='akhilsai.innovkraft@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
                $subject='Form Submission';
                $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
                $headers="From: ".$email;

                $sentmail=swiftmail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                header('localtion:index.html');            
          } 
          else{ 
            echo "ERROR:"; 
        } 
       
       
    
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Feedback Form</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="main">
        
        <div class="info">Give Your Feedback!</div>
        
        <form action="#" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
            
            <label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required><br>
            
            <label for="email">Email ID</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required><br>
            
            <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required><br>
            
            <label for="message">Message</label><br>
            <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here..." required></textarea><br>
            
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub-btn">
    
        </form>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
include ('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
        $phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['phone']);
        $msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['msg']);
        
        
        $sql="insert into contact(`name`,`email`,`phone`,`msg`) values('$name','$email','$phone','$msg')";
    //  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        
        
         if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){ 
                $to='akhilsai.innovkraft@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
                $subject='Form Submission';
                $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
                $headers="From: ".$email;

                $sentmail=swiftmail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                header('localtion:index.html');            
          } 
          else{ 
            echo "ERROR:"; 
        } 
       
       
    
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Feedback Form</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="main">
        
        <div class="info">Give Your Feedback!</div>
        
        <form action="#" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
            
            <label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required><br>
            
            <label for="email">Email ID</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required><br>
            
            <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required><br>
            
            <label for="message">Message</label><br>
            <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here..." required></textarea><br>
            
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub-btn">
    
        </form>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```